# Grouped Result in Solr

Tags: content-search, solr, multilingual

I have seen documentation mentioning `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrNetExtension` for Sitecore 9 indicating that its able to group results by a field (ie: `_group` field).  What I am unable to find is a nice and easy way to do this in Sitecore 8.  What I had hoped to achieve was to simply append

```
fq=group=true&group.field=_group&group.main=true
```

to the query as a `FilterQuery`. What I have tried thus far has been creating a custom `QueryNode` called `GroupByField(keySelector)` to inject a custom `SolrQuery` into the `SolrQueryMapperState.FilterQuery` with no luck.  I have also tried to use the

```
.Filter(x => x["group"] == "true" && x["group.field"] == 
    BuildInFields.Group && x["group.main"] == "true")
```

But that yielded a `no field group found` which does make sense since it's not a field in the index itself.

**TL;DR**: Ultimately what I need is, when a User searches a keyword, the search is conducted across all languages and items, but only the items related to the results in the current languages are returned (if I put in a word that is found on the `en-gb` version of the item, I want the .  I assumed this was what the `group` functionality in Solr was built for.  At this point I am considering doing a self join, joining the non-grouped results and matching on the `group` of a language specific but am not sure that's going to be the solution either.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read you dont want grouping (which would be for getting some results for EVERY language

Something like

```
context.GetQueryable<MySearchResultItem>().Where(item => item.Language
== context.Language)
```

If you have multiple "current languages" you should have an OR condition on the Where term for multiple languages.

Comment: Maybe I'll need to update my initial question, but I do want some results from all languages in a sense. I want the current culture variant of any item match in any language.

Comment: Then I am not sure of what you are trying to accomplish. Can you add some examples of data and output needed?